# Incompatible types when create Loader

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have some problem with Loaders.
I have Fragment, he implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
When I do onCreateLoader, occurs error **Incompatible types**. (Wrong Context)
I code samples uses "getActivity()" or "getContext()". How to resolve error? Thanks.

**Fragment**

```
public class FitnessDataFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<AllFitnessDataModel>> {
    private Loader<List<AllFitnessDataModel>> loader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loader = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, getArguments(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<AllFitnessDataModel>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new AsyncTracksLoader(getActivity(),args);
    }
```

**Loader**

```
public class AsyncTracksLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<AllFitnessDataModel>> {
private List<AllFitnessDataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private int typeReminder;

public AsyncTracksLoader(Context context, Bundle args) {
    super(context);
    if (args != null) {
        typeReminder = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    super.onStartLoading();
    if(dataModelList!=null){
        deliverResult(dataModelList);
    }else {
        forceLoad();
    }
}


@Override
public List<AllFitnessDataModel> loadInBackground() {
    //do something
    return dataModelList;
}


@Override
public void deliverResult(List<AllFitnessDataModel> data) {
    dataModelList = data;
    super.deliverResult(data);
}
}
```

**Imports Fragment**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.egoriku.catsrunning.App;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.R;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.activities.ScamperActivity;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.activities.TrackOnMapsActivity;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.activities.TracksActivity;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.adapters.FitnessDataAdapter;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.adapters.interfaces.IOnItemHandlerListener;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.loaders.AsyncTracksLoader;
import com.egoriku.catsrunning.models.AllFitnessDataModel;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
```

Comment: Can you also add the imports so that we can compare.

Comment: Actually this one `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, getArguments(), this);` does not compile to me because it is an Activity and not a FragmentActivity, unless you cast it.

Comment: I change this to FitnessDataFragment.this. But is still bug.

Comment: if you are using fragment then use `getLoaderManager` because `getSupportLoaderManager` is used when you are using the Fragment activity.

Comment: Thanks. I changed on getLoaderManager  (not support) and it's work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments have their own loader managers - try calling `getLoaderManager()` instead of `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()`.

Also make sure that you're being consistent in terms of whether you're using `android.app` or `android.support.v4.app` for `LoaderManager`, `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One thing more to make sure is when you are writing "implements ..." and suggestion pops up , make sure that you select the correct version according to how you implemented your loader . There are two versions of it . One is the support one and one is the normal one .